# Evaluation of $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac{r}{n^2+n+r}$

Tags: calculus, limits, riemann-sum, harmonic-numbers

> Evaluation of $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac{r}{n^2+n+r}$$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $$L = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac{r}{n^2+n+r} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac{\frac{r}{n}}{\frac{r^2}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{r}{n^2}}\cdot \frac{1}{n}$$

I want to convert into Reinmann Integral, But it is not possible here.

So How can I solve it

Help me

Thanks

Comment: No i Think It must g o to $0$

Comment: Can you see that it's less than $\frac{n^2}{n^2+n+r}$? for all $n$?

Comment: If you plug in $n=\infty$ its just 0 as $1/n=1/\infty=0$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$\frac{r}{(n+1)^2}\leq\frac{r}{n^2+n+r}\leq\frac{r}{n^2}$$
hence your limit equals $\int_{0}^{1}x\,dx = \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}$.

You may also avoid Riemann sums by just noticing that $\sum_{r=1}^{n} r = \frac{n^2+n}{2}$.

Answer (score 4):

Besides Jack's neat answer, a different approach giving more than the desired limit.

One may rewrite your sum with the standard [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) 
$$
\begin{align}
\sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac{r}{n^2+n+r}&=\sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac{n^2+n+r-(n^2+n)}{n^2+n+r}\\\\&=n-(n^2+n)\sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac1{n^2+n+r}\\\\
&=n-(n^2+n)\left(H_{n^2+2n}- H_{n^2+n+1}\right)
\end{align}
$$ then use the asymptotics of [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation), as $ N \to \infty$, 
$$
H_N=\log N+\gamma+\frac1{2N}-\frac1{12N^2}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac1{N^4} \right)
$$ leading readily to

> $$
> \sum^{n}_{r=1}\frac{r}{n^2+n+r}=\frac12-\frac1{3n}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac1{n^2} \right)
> $$

as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: I just finished typing the same when your answer came. You are too fast for the old man ! Cheers.