# Direct evaluation of Limit of a sum

Tags: limits, summation

I was trying to solve this problem:
$$L=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty }{\sum_{r=1}^{n}\dfrac{r}{n^2+n+r}}$$

I managed to prove that it is $\tfrac{1}{2}$ using the Sandwich theorem.
Is there some way, to either:

1. Convert this into an integral
2. Evaluate this sum directly.

Comment: I can't see a way to express that sum as a Riemann sum... but perhaps there is one, with substitution or something.

Comment: You did it like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1585305/11619)?

Answer (score 2):

$$S_n={\sum_{r=1}^{n}\dfrac{r}{n^2+n+r}}=n(n+1) \left(H_{n(n+1)}-H_{n (n+2)}\right)+n$$

Using the asymptotics of harmonic numbers
$$S_n=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3 n}+\frac{5}{12 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$n\int_0^1\frac x{n+1+x}\mathrm dx\leq\sum_{r=1}^n\frac r{n^2+n+r}\leq\frac 12$$
for
$$\sum_{r=1}^n\frac r{n^2+n+r}\leq\frac 1{n^2+n}\sum_{r=1}^nr=\frac 12$$
and on the other hand:
\begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^n\frac r{n^2+n+r}
&=n\sum_{r=1}^n\frac{r/n}{n+1+r/n}\frac 1n\\
&\geq n\int_0^1\frac x{n+1+x}\mathrm dx\\
&=n\left(1-(n+1)\log\left(1+\frac 1{n+1}\right)\right)\\
&\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\frac 12
\end{align}